# Python 3.8.3 to Mysql 5.0 connection issues

Tags: python, mysql, connection

I am trying to connect to a Mysql5.0 database on a server using Mysql-connector-python version 1.2.3 which I understand is the latest version that should work with Mysql 5.0, albeit with possible irregularities, and NO, I cannot update to a newer version of Mysql

I get the error message:
"Error while connecting to MySQL Authentication with old (insecure) passwords is not supported. For more information, lookup Password Hashing in the latest MySQL manual"
I have tried reading the manual on that topic and cannot understand head nor tail of it.

My coding is

```
try:
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='XXXX.XXX',
                                         database='XXXX',
                                         user='XXXXX',
                                         password='XXXXX')
    if connection.is_connected():
        db_Info = connection.get_server_info()
        print("Connected to MySQL Server version ", db_Info)
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("select database();")
        record = cursor.fetchone()
        print("You're connected to database: ", record)
except Error as e:
    print("Error while connecting to MySQL", e)
finally:
    if connection.is_connected():
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()
        print("MySQL connection is closed")
```

Basically, is there a way of connecting Python 3.8 to a Mysql 5.0 database, even if using a different library, and if so how?
Is it just a case of choosing a newer and longer password. The current one was created for Mysql 5.0, so could that be the issue?

Thanks for any help or links to sites that may help, as I cannot find anything about older versions or what Password Hashing on Mysql actually means, at least not in laymans terms ;)

Comment: Run `SELECT * FROM mysql.user` then look at `Password` column. Then [take a look at this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=bd70f1aa1a84dfa9f3bac81e58b4e190) and tell us which one styled similar to your password.

Comment: Thanks I will ask my host, as the Db password is one of the few things I do not have access to.
Would I be correct in thinking it needs to be in the second format?

Comment: We have similar issue when using PHP connecting to MySQL db with the `OLD_PASSWORD` format as well. This type of 16 bytes password hashing were [the default hashing before 4.1.1](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/password-hashing.html) and was changed to a more secure 41 bytes hashing. I guess it's only natural that Python (and others) are not supporting the old password hashing anymore, since it wasn't the default from 2004 onwards. So, yes, the second format is currently the supported format.